# angular.js jsonp error status 404

Tags: .net, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I have a SPA and I am trying to fetch JSON data from remote .NET WebAPI with angular `$http.jsonp`

```
var widgetApp = angular.module('widgetApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});

widgetApp.controller('topStreaksCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  $http.jsonp('http://REMOTESERVER.azurewebsites.net/api/Serie/getdata?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
     .success(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(config);
    })
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['widgetApp']);
```

I can see response data on Chrome network but jsonp function always return error. status 404 ?
Any config needed on WebAPI?

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to serve static data from Azure you'll need to add the following to your `Web.config` otherwise you'll receive the 404 because the json MIME Type is not set by default

### [Reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```